# Box offset when using the pure css framework

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

I'm using [pure css](http://purecss.io/) for my website. The problem is, that the boxes have a weird offset, that is definied nowhere The boxes don't move even when I set padding and margin to zero. This causes the last box to move in the second row.

HTML:

```
<div class="pure-u-4-24 outer">
<div class="inner-ib inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-5-24 outer">
<div class="inner-ib inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-11-24 outer">
<div class="inner-ib inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-4-24 outer ">
<div class="inner-ib inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
  background-color: rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.75);
}
 .outer {
   padding-top: 10vh;
}
.inner-ib{
  height: 90vh;
}
```

[How the website looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNseo.png)

Comment: That won't help. We need the relevant source (HTML and CSS). Try to boil the website down to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue and put that in a snippet here in the question. (Edit the question; click the `<>` icon.)

Comment: And, you can do [inline links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024572/box-offset-when-using-the-pure-css-framework) like this: \[link name\]\(lLINK_URL\)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything inside the `pure-g` container for your columns to work correctly..

http://codeply.com/go/rVcX2Bhpko

```
<div class="pure-g"> 
      ..
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, well. Somtimes you miss the forest for the trees. Thanks!